# beautifulSoup give me none

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

hi i am trying to build a simple program and i need a to scrap a letter from the web every second but when i scrap  that letter it shows [ ] when i use find_all or None when i use find . can someone help me please i don't want to get deep  in web scraping not yet at least.

the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time


while True :
    time.sleep(1)
    html_text = requests.get('https://jklm.fun/RVZC').text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
    let = soup.find('div', class_ = 'syllable')
    print(let)
```

terminal:

`None`

i don't know if you well need this but i will put a screenshot of the inspect and the letters i want to scrap.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

requests.get('https://jklm.fun/RVZC') returns the page before your target.
The one where you have to put the nickname and click on the ok button.

Maybe you'll need selenium to come to a solution.